# Edit a CSV file dynamically

Tags: android

I build a recycler view from a CSV file. After I click a button, I need to edit a field in the CSV file and re-build the recycler view. Android file system is read-only, so I have to create a new file located in the external storage directory. But when I build the recycler view starting from this new file, it is empty. Why?

(Before all this, I verify storage permissions)

Create the rw file ("rw_file.csv") from the original csv ("catalog.csv"):

```
public void createRWFile(Context context)
    {
        String source = "catalog.csv";
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File rw_file = new File(root, "rw_file.csv");

        try
        {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(source)),';');
            List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();

            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(rw_file),';',' ');
            writer.writeAll(csvBody);
            writer.flush();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Read the new csv file and store it in a LinkedList: (MUST BE AN ERROR HERE)

```
public void fillCatalog(String filename)
    {
        catalog.clear();    

        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getContext().getAssets().open(filename)),';');
            List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();

            for(String[] i : csvBody)
            {
                Book curr = new Book();

                curr.author = i[0];
                curr.title = i[1];
                curr.genre = i[4];
                curr.cover = getResources().getIdentifier(i[5], "drawable", "com.example.rese.biblioteca_3");
                curr.availability = getResources().getIdentifier(i[6], "drawable", "com.example.rese.biblioteca_3");

                if(curr.genre.equals("Classico"))
                    catalog.add(curr);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Create the Recycler View (in the OnCreate method):

```
fillCatalog("catalog.csv");     //TODO se metto rw_file non funziona
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.classici_rv);
mAdapter = new BookListAdapter(getContext(), catalog);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

Comment: `Android file system is read-only,` No. Not at all. Please elaborate.

Comment: `so I have to create a new file located in the external storage directory.` So not read only. And there are other places then external memory you can use.

Comment: `writer.flush();` Add a `writer.close();`

Comment: `(Before all this, I verify storage permissions)` It is unclear what you are doing.

Comment: `Read the new csv file and store it in a LinkedList:` You are clearly not reading the new file but the old file again. But it is unclear which filename you use. Not very informative.

Comment: If I create a file not starting from the getExternalStorageDirectory, I receive the error "open failed EROFS - read only file system).
As I wrote in the comment, if I build the recycler view from the new file ("rw_file.csv"), the recycler view is empty

Comment: Sadly you did not come to the point. And talking about a recyclview makes no sense. Your only concern should be writing and reading a file. But you did not come to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem! I can't modify a file (or better, it's difficult), but I can store all datas in a structure, like a LinkedList), then I can edit datas and build recycler views from that structure.

In the MainActivity I fill the structure

```
public void fillCatalog(String filename)
    {
        catalog.clear();   

        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("catalog.csv")),';');
            List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();

            for(String[] i : csvBody)
            {
                ...
                catalog.add(...);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and in my activity I fill the recycler view:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classici_tab, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.classici_rv);
        mAdapter = new BookListAdapter(getContext(), MainActivity.catalog);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return fragmentView;
    }
```

Somewhere I edit the datas, then I recall the onCreateView to show the modifies.